# You must call 'the_content' function in the current template, in order for Elementor to work on this page

Tags: wordpress, web, wordpress-theming, wordpress-6

When I click on "Edit with Elementor" I get an error message saying:

> Sorry, the content area was not found in your page.
>
> You must call 'the_content' function in the current template, in order for Elementor to work on this page.

[image: Screenshot of a post/page edit screen]

[image: Screenshot of error message indicating that current template doesn't seem to be using "the_content()" function]

Is the code below correct?

[image: Screenshot of template code]

Comment: Code seems correct IMO. Make sure you're picking the right page template on the Page Edit screen (see sidebar > Page > template).

Comment: im in the right template https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3LAr.png

Comment: i cant resolve this problem please help

Comment: Not there, on the Page Edit screen Aizen.

Comment: now what should i do https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Uo0n.png

Comment: Pick the "Full Width Template" option (see tpl-fluid.php, the template name is there as well) then save changes and try again.

Comment: the problem is still https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxCVB.png

Comment: Did you refresh the page after saving changes?

Comment: Yes, I refreshed the page

Comment: No idea then, maybe someone else will know. Alternatively you can also reach out to Elementor's Support team and have them assist you with this.

Comment: React to Elementor, or search on existing issues in forum github. it's a kind of common issue, encountered by many people.